# Generate json key for Google Cloud permissions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-authentication

I have a project and wish to generate a new json key for my service account. I need to do it from app engine via the sdk. Is this possible; I can't find the library? Or can it *only* be created manually in the console?

Comment: It can only be done manually though console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one API that lets you manipulate the projects on Google Developer console its called [Google Cloud Resource manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/).   Here is some notes on my testing of it.  [Google Developer console API](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-api/)

This API is still in BETA and very new. currently all it lets you do is insert update delete list and get projects.  You cant do anything with the settings of the project.

I have been unable to track down any kind of support forum or request forum for this API.   It would be nice if they would extend it so we can make changes to the consent screen, oauth credentials and API settings. Not to mention check the Quota programmatically.

Comment: Yeah I need to specifically manipulate the api permissions. This is what I thought, pity Google is wanting in some regards.